# How to split data frame with multiple delimiter using str_split_fixed?

Tags: r, stringr

How can i split a column  separated by multiple delimiter into separate columns in data frame

```
read.table(text = " Chr  Nm1 Nm2 Nm3
    chr10_100064111-100064134+Nfif   20  20 20
    chr10_100064115-100064138-Kitl   30 19 40
    chr10_100076865-100076888+Tert   60 440 18
    chr10_100079974-100079997-Itg    50 11 23                
    chr10_100466221-100466244+Tmtc3  55 24 53", header = TRUE)


              Chr              gene   Nm1 Nm2 Nm3
    chr10_100064111-100064134 Nfif   20  20 20
    chr10_100064115-100064138 Kitl   30 19 40
    chr10_100076865-100076888 Tert   60 440 18
    chr10_100079974-100079997 Itg    50 11 23 12                
    chr10_100466221-100466244 Tmtc3  55 24 53 12
```

i used

```
library(stringr)
df2 <- str_split_fixed(df1$name, "\\+", 2)
```

I would like to know how can we include both + and - delimiter

Comment: Use a regex character class in `str_split` with `"[+-]"` or use a pipe `+|-`. Also, I'm not sure you're gaining anything here from `stringr` that regular `strsplit` doesn't already do well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're trying to split one column into multiple, `tidyr::separate` is handy:

```
library(tidyr)

dat %>% separate(Chr, into = paste0('Chr', 1:3), sep = '[+-]')

#              Chr1      Chr2  Chr3 Nm1 Nm2 Nm3
# 1 chr10_100064111 100064134  Nfif  20  20  20
# 2 chr10_100064115 100064138  Kitl  30  19  40
# 3 chr10_100076865 100076888  Tert  60 440  18
# 4 chr10_100079974 100079997   Itg  50  11  23
# 5 chr10_100466221 100466244 Tmtc3  55  24  53
```

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```
str_split_fixed(a, "[-+]", 2)
```

Comment: You need to use `str_split` (or `strsplit`) if you're using regex, not `str_split_fixed`.

Comment: From the str_split_fixed documentation: 
"The default interpretation is a regular expression, as described in stringi-search-regex. Control options with regex()"
Also I tested it and seems to work

Comment: Hmm, you are correct! ...though that's a very confusingly named set of functions given base R regex `fixed = TRUE` behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do this in base R with `strsplit`:

```
# split Chr into a list
tempList <- strsplit(as.character(df$Chr), split="[+-]")

# replace Chr with desired values
df$Chr <- sapply(tempList, function(i) paste(i[[1]], i[[2]], sep="-"))

# get Gene variable
df$gene <- sapply(tempList, "[[", 3)
```

Comment: when tried  df$gene <- sapply(tempList, "[[", 3)                                            Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : subscript out of bounds

Comment: @beginner I just copied and pasted your example data.frame, naming it df, and then copied and pasted my suggested solution and did not receive this error.